# Is it possible to Implement a shared resource in PHP?

Tags: php, shared-libraries, php-extension

Lets say, there is a config file which lists all the JavaScript files used by the webapp.
This config file has not just the names but paths to their respective location. & This content will be used by all the users on a site.

Imagine this for all the style sheets, images, scripts etc

> - This is more or less like a global resource for all the users.
> - Loading this for each and every user would cause more memory usage.

*`Is there a way this resource could be made shared?`*

As in,

> - always in memory
> - and only one copy for all the users.

---

> Do I need to write a PHP extension for this?
>   say like xdebug and load it in php.ini?

*PHP is not serving any static content here. It is for providing easier way to include the path to files(static files). This will help while coding.*

Comment: You just need php opcode cache

Comment: Javascript, stylesheets, images and every other resources are retrieved from the browser directly without affecting PHP in any way, so: Why?

Comment: @zerkms looking into PHP opcode cache

Comment: @KingCrunch Its for a dependency injection module that I have implemented.

Comment: @zerkms how will a PHP opcode cache as memcache help?

Comment: DI exists to decouple dependencies between classes. I don't understand what static resources have to do with this :? PHP usually never touch JS, ... files

Comment: There are shared memory options (shmop or memcached), but you would still copy it into each PHPs runtime local memory to actually use it (or before sending it). Not sure if that is worth the effort. A simple config file and `readfile()` might be more efficient if it's just a dependency list. (Maybe you can concretise the data scheme a bit, even if just in planning stage.)

Comment: @KingCrunch Yes, you are write what I am trying to do is providing  easier way to include the path to files(static files). This will help while coding.

Comment: @mario Currently, I am doing the config file & readFile() way. If I am required to copy it into each PHPs runtime local memory to actually use it. Then I think its not worth it.
The data scheme has been concretised to some extent since I have already Implemented it.

Comment: @ThinkMonkey: If you are using just `readfile` then it isn't copied into memory. Caching is handled by the OS then as well. It's just if you load it and need to access or modify individual array attributes that you need it in local memory. Then it won't matter if you use a local file or memcached / shmop.

Comment: Ok so the actual question is not "How do I store the resources in memory for fast access?" but "How do I keep in memory the data inside my configuration file?" (which you're mentioning in your question, holding the paths to the resources).

Comment: @mario I have the contents converted into an array. And I am accessing them from there. readFile:convert to required array format:accessing it.

Comment: Then you can keep using the file. No shared memory option will allow you to actually save memory then. For PHP to access array entries, it needs to have an array `zval` first. (I could think of a cumbersome `ArrayAccess` workaround. But that would be trading significant speed for probably zilch memory savings.)

Comment: @Flavius No! I have the contents converted into an array. And I am accessing them from there. readFile:convert to required array format:accessing it.
Since this resource (array) Is universal to the application in turn to all the users. I am looking for, whether it can be made into a shared resource. instead of every user having a copy!(as described in the question :P)

Comment: @mario hmmmm.. `Please post your comments as an answer.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming from what you said your using Apache.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

APC plugin provides byte-code compilation for a speed boost and also provides a data store. See apc_add/apc_store funcs.

Haven't tried it's data store, but it's speed boost is good.

Comment: looking into it.. need some time.

Comment: tried the data store working fine until now :). Although, I still need to copy the data into each PHP's run-time local memory to actually use it (pointed to by @mario).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you'd use PHP to serve static content, but:

I usually use memcached for storing shared resources. It's very effective and fast.

But really, you shouldn't let PHP serve static content.

Comment: PHP is not serving any static content. It is for providing easier way to include the path to files(static files). This will help while coding.